# pop up window showing user current location twice in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, sencha-touch-2

I am using sencha touch 2 framework to build my app. The problem is i am displaying map in the application, where the pop up window is displaying twice in the ipad. Ideally the location pop up is expected to show once,please can i know any  settings is triggering this pop up window twice , or is their any coding changes through sencha touch framework has triggered this occurence.

[image]

Comment: reffer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967173/ios-why-does-turn-on-location-services-alert-show-twice-upon-startup

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I found the following info on the phonegap wiki that might help you as well.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494770/FAQ

The interesting part is:

> The latest solution for iPhone OS 4.x and PhoneGap 0.9.x is to follow
>   the example of the docs for and add an event listener that **waits for
>   the device to be ready, otherwise the native navigator.geolocation is
>   used and you get an alert like this**:
>   "var/mobile/Applications/UUID/appname.app/www/index.html" Would Like
>   To Use Your Current Location.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12740258/956779) I used to solve this in PhoneGap 2.1.0 .  You can just drop it into your index.js exactly as-is, and put your own code in the myCustomJS() callback handler.  It will work in desktop and mobile browsers and within PhoneGap / Cordova apps.