# How to identify when iOS prompts "Turn on Location Service" alert?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

In my app this alert shows multiple times.
Similar issue: [iOS: Why does "Turn on Location Services" alert show twice upon startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967173/ios-why-does-turn-on-location-services-alert-show-twice-upon-startup).

[image: Screenshot of alert]

How to identify when iOS prompts "Turn on Location Service" alert?

**Scenario to see two alert in Google map app.**

1. Turn off Location services of device
2. Install of Google map app from AppStore. (If your device already have Google map app. Uninstall existing app from device and install the app from AppStore)
3. Launch the app
4. Mentioned alert will display
5. Tap on "Cancel"
6. Quit the app
7. Launch the app again
8. Mentioned alert will display again.

**Another scenario to see more than two alert in Google map app.**

1. Turn off Location services of device
2. Install of Google map app from AppStore. (If your device already have Google map app. Uninstall existing app from device and install the app from AppStore)
3. Launch the app
4. Mentioned alert will display
5. Lock the screen
6. Wait for 20 seconds (You may need to wait for extra time if your device have more RAM)
7. Unlock the screen and quit the app promptly (If you couldn't able to quit the app promptly, repeat from step 5)
8. Launch the app again
9. Mentioned alert will display
10. Repeat from step 5 to see the mentioned alert again and again.

Comment: whats wrong in it ? have you prompted to alert any time ? 
if yes then do you want to show this alert once in application life time ?

Comment: if you have not prompted to alert and and quit app it shows alert again its a good approach ? if you do want to show it once in life time of app then store some pref values in application memory.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan As per my customer requirement I developed an alert with the same functionality. And It will be showing whenever the status giving as 'denied' or 'restricted' in "func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus)" delegate. So I want to avoid the alert that I developed whenever OS shows the mentioned alert in the question.

Comment: i think draw back is in your code why don't you post code where request for location manages is checked and asked.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Sorry, I didn't understand your point. Could you make it more clear?

Comment: can you post your code where you are showing alert for location permissions

Comment: @AbuUlHassan
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if (status == .denied || status == .restricted) {
            //showing alert with titile:"Enable location to send information based on your area." and On "Settings" button action will be redirecting to settings app, On "Cancel" button action, nothing will be doing so alert will disappear.
        }
    }

Comment: hmmm means OS and your application showing two alerts one from app and one from IOS ?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan. Yes, that is the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194225/discussion-between-abu-ul-hassan-and-shebin-koshy).

Answer (score 0):

I know this not a good approach but to solve the problem it should work

```
if window.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.last?.isKind(of: UIAlertController){
//Do not show your alert  
    }
else{
//show your alert
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and time, OS prompting alert are not presenting from our applications window or view controller. proof:https://i.imgur.com/gXFGodQ.png. This image is take by following scenario. 1.Turn off Location services of device. 2.Install Google map app from AppStore. (If your device already have Google map app. Uninstall existing app from device and install the app from AppStore) 3.Launch the app and minimize the app promptly(if you couldn't able to reproduce retry from step 1) 4.OS prompted alert can be see in Home screen of the device.

Comment: am unable to see image its just placeholder

Comment: any how its not app window its mobile window like  this 

  let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

Comment: Reposting the image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w5R6fuur-u0MluwyO9432O_yJlgxWtS8/view?usp=sharing